# django ignore slash in url and take parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

hi i have url like this:

```
path('api/v1/store/download/<str:ix>/', DownloadVideoAPI.as_view(), name='download'),
```

it accept long string .

I want to keep allthing after `download` key in above URL as the parameter.

but when I enter a long string that contains some slash Django says page not found for example when if enter `"/api/v1/store/download/asdasd2asdsadas/asdasd"` will give me 404 not found ...

how can I do that?

this is my view:

```
class DownloadVideoAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, ix):
        pre = ix.split(",")
        hash = pre[0]
        dec = pre[1]
        de_hash = decode_data(hash, dec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It's possible to add the extra parameters in the request. you can use re_path method.

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(r'api/v1/store/download/(?P<ix>\w+)/', DownloadVideoAPI.as_view(), name='download'),
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
path('api/v1/store/download/<str:ix>', DownloadVideoAPI.as_view(), name='download'),
```

without `/` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`/api/v1/store/download/asdasd2asdsadas/asdasd` will result in a `404` page since Django cannot map the URL, `/api/v1/store/download/asdasd2asdsadas/`, to a route in your `urls.py`. To solve this, aside from using BugHunter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50076692/1116098), you could URL encode your long string first before passing it to your URL.

So, given the long string, `"asdasd2asdsadas/asdasd"`, URL encode it first to `"asdasd2asdsadas%2Fasdasd"`. Once you have encoded it, your URL should now look like `"/api/v1/store/download/asdasd2asdsadas%2Fasdasd`".

---

To URL encode in Python 3, you can use `urllib`.

```
import urllib

parameter = 'asdasd2asdsadas/asdasd'
encoded_string = urllib.quote(parameter, safe='')
```

`encoded_string` here should have the value, `"asdasd2asdsadas%2Fasdasd"`.